# How does one insert XSLT elements with attributes inside of javascript inside of a html attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, escaping

Question summary: What changes do I have to make to make the following xslt document valid.

The following is a simplified version of a theme document I am trying to modify for a Gizmox WebGUI DataGrid control.  The issue I am having with it is the horrendous onclick event attribute on the button element.  I have tried the code both this way, and with `&quot;` in place of `"` for the attribute quotes.  In neither case does the document validate.  I could do some of the work in the javascript method, and probably will before I am done, but I would still need to pass the value of `<xsl:value-of select="@Attr.TotalPages"/>` as a parameter in that case as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:WC="wgcontrols">
    <xsl:template name="tplListDrawPaging">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="List-PagingPanel" dir="{$dir}" align="center">
      <tr>
          <td width="150px" align="right" class="Common-FontData" dir="ltr">
              <span>Go to page:</span>
              <input type="text" id="{@Id}-goToPageTextBox" name="{@Id}-goToPageTextBox" style="width:35px;" />
              <button type="button" onclick="var goToValue = getElementById('{@Id}-goToPageTextBox').value;
                                        if(goToValue &lt;= 0){goToValue = 1;}
                                        else if(goToValue &gt; <xsl:value-of select="@Attr.TotalPages"/>){goToValue = <xsl:value-of select="@Attr.TotalPages"/>;})
                                        List_NavigateTo('{@Id}',goToValue);">Go</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [escape the curly braces](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) inside the expression by doubling them:

```
<button type="button" onclick="var goToValue = document.getElementById('{@Id}-goToPageTextBox').value; if (goToValue &lt;= 0) {{ goToValue = 1; }} else if (goToValue &gt; {@Attr.TotalPages}) {{ goToValue = {@Attr.TotalPages}; }} List_NavigateTo('{@Id}', goToValue);">Go</button>
```

I would definitely put that code inside its own function and call that from the `onclick` handler, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I had no idea that <xsl:value-of select="@Attr.TotalPages"/> and {@Attr.TotalPages} were equivalent.  I need to brush up on my xslt obviously.  And it definitely makes sense that I would have to escape the curly brackets as well.